# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(); not running program

Tags: linux, debian, java, proc

the problem is that I am trying to make a game launcher and when you log in it goes and starts the actual game.

the code I have been told to do this is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();`

i can run simple programs like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("firefox");` but when i try to run my program, it does not start.

this is my code

```
Map<String, String> g = System.getenv(); //find home dir
System.out.println("java -jar " + g.get("HOME") + "/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + g.get("HOME") + "/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar");
```

I have also tried

```
Map<String, String> g = System.getenv(); //find home dir
System.out.println("java -jar " + g.get("HOME") + "/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar");
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + g.get("HOME") +
                                         "/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar");
```

I am using linux Debian

with `java -version` ouput

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

all help apreciated

Comment: java -jar ... , did you try this from command line?

Comment: Do you get any sort of exception?

Comment: Why not? `java -jar` will execute a JAR file, based on the `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest file.

Comment: Yes it will run as long as the Manifest is defined with main class and classpath if any. Needed to know if this was working

Comment: Yeah... I'm wrong. I assume that does work when it's run simply on the command line?

Comment: @rajesh, yes, I understand. Another commenter mentioned that it shouldn't work at all (that comment has since been deleted).

Comment: @Isaac, I was replying to that comment. Should have tagged to avoid ambiguity :)

Comment: Yes i have run this in the terminal and all works fine. and i will check the manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't explain what happens when you try to run `java -jar` (exception? anything? do you get a `Process` object back?), I can think of one reason why it happens. Your `HOME` environment variable contains a space (you're under Windows, aren't you), and that confuses `exec()`.

If my theory is correct, then `exec()` is actually parsing your one-string command as follows: assuming `HOME`=`C:\Documents and Settings\Myself` -

*Execute program named `java`, passing in the following arguments:*

1. *`-jar`*
2. *`C:\Documents`*
3. *`and`*
4. *`Settings\Myself\whatever.jar`*

The safest way to execute would be to pass in an array of strings, instead.

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] {"java", "-jar", g.get("HOME")+"/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar"});
```

Comment: Didnt know that you can pass an array as param to exec. +1

Comment: I am on Linux Debian so what it should look like exactly is        `java -jar /home/USER/.2DMC/bin/2DG.jar USERNAME: User`

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. it was on my 2nd jars side. I wasn't loading some libs correctly so it didn't work from different locations.

I have fixed my problems. thanks for the help

Comment: If this is the solution to your question, please mark it as such by clicking the accept icon (the "V" mark to the left of this answer).  Thanks.

Comment: @OptimusPrime, FuZi0nHD is the one who asked the question, so he/she can judge what solves the problem and what doesn't.  Don't direct your comment at me.  If you think this is a bad answer, direct your comment at he/she who provided the answer, or vote it down.

Comment: The question/answer would be helpful if you explain the problem, provide the complete solution to your problem, and the procedure you followed to solve the problem.